# first row is always missing when getting the result in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

getting `pg_num_rows = 1` but not able to fetch the row

```
$recordset = $obj_d->search_routing($this);
if(pg_num_rows($recordset)>0)
{
    if($row = pg_fetch_row($recordset))
    {
        $this->diallingprefix=$row[2];
        $this->forceroute=$row[5];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure pg_num_rows is greater than zero? The code above doesn't show anything when it's true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`while( $row = pg_fetch_row($recordset) ) { }`

Comment: i used while also but if there is only one row coming in the output then while doesn't  matter

Comment: i used for loop also but not able to fetch the row

Comment: @AshokBarthwal paste `var_dump($recordset);` and `var_dump($row;`